# getting an error when dispatching store action

Tags: angular, ngrx

i have a model that looks like this.

```
    export class BankAccount {
  id?: string;
  accountNumber: string;
  accountTitle: string;
  userImage: string;
  currentBalance: number;
  email: string;
  phoneNumber: string;
  accountStatus: AccountStatus;
}
export enum AccountStatus {
  Active = 0,
  InActive = 1,
}
```

and action is defined like this.

```
export const bankAccountCreating = createAction(
'[Create New Account Component] Account Creating',
 props<{ acct: BankAccount }>()
);
```

so i have an angular form that populates and object and dispatches

```
 this.store.dispatch(bankAccountCreating({ acct: this.bankAccount }));
```

here i get the error

> Detected unserializable action at acct

please note that i have no reducer for this action as it just triggers effect but doesn't update store.

[image]
**update**
[image]

```
    export class BankAccount {
  id?: string;
  accountNumber: string;
  accountTitle: string;
  userImage?: string;
  currentBalance: number;
  email: string;
  phoneNumber: string;
  // accountStatus: AccountStatus;
}
export enum AccountStatus {
  Active = 0,
  InActive = 1,
}
```

Comment: bank account is a interface?

Comment: it is a class as mentioned above in the code

Comment: try changing class to interface?

Comment: actually there is a form with 2 way binding because of that i have to initialize it in constructor. otherwise i get an error when empty form loads.

Comment: please find my response below.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your data.

Your class is defined as :-

```
 export class BankAccount {
  id?: string;
  accountNumber: string;
  accountTitle: string;
  userImage: string;
  currentBalance: number;
  email: string;
  phoneNumber: string;
  accountStatus: AccountStatus;
}
```

you are dispatching current balance as string which should be a number, accountStatus as string which expects a accountstatus object, and there is no userimage string which is mandatory.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215869/discussion-on-answer-by-aakash-garg-getting-an-error-when-dispatching-store-acti).

Answer (score 0):

A class is not serializable, you can use an interface to fix this issue or disable the serializability runtime checks.

See the [docs](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/configuration/runtime-checks) for more info.

Comment: actually there is a form with 2 way binding because of that i have to initialize it in constructor. otherwise i get an error when empty form loads

Comment: Have you tried making it an interface or disabling the runtime checks?